# where is the properties file I can read from settingsReader in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, application-settings

I am studying some C# code and I wonder where is the file that is read using this lines:

```
 System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = new AppSettingsReader();

        string key = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("MyProperty", typeof(String));
```

I want to get the `MyProperty` value without running the code.
I am using VS2015.

Thank you

Comment: Depends on the scope of the setting.  If it is "Application" then it is stored in the appname.config file in the same directory as appname.exe.  If it is "User' then it is stored in the user.config file in a hard-to-find subdirectory of AppData.  Just looking at the code gives no insight in where to look.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the `App.config` file in your solution.

After you compile the code, it will be next to your exe file with the name of your exe (e.g `MyExeName.exe.config`)

Comment: there is no such file in my solution, the only file .config is Authorization.config

Comment: and does not contain this property, any other file?

Comment: did you try to search the property name in the whole solution? it should be in a file with the extention .config

Comment: Are you sure this file \ property exists?  Right click on the project -> Properties -> Settings. Is there a default settings file with the property you are searching?